# FindSystemTimeZoneByID in TimeZone

Tags: asp.net, timezone

I want to know whether **"FindSystemTimeZoneByID"** will check the client system timezone or will it be checking the server system timezone where the application has been hosted ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The servers' timezone. You'll probably have to look into some Javascript to get the clients timezone: Check out the [Date.getTimezoneOffset()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getTimezoneOffset.asp) method, it may be what you're looking for. And there's even a [few suggestions here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274826/how-to-get-client-date-and-time-in-asp-net) to solve your problem. :)

Answer (score 1):

It will only check the server's system.