# Client system time in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

This C# code `DateTime.Now;` notes server time and this code `DateTimeKind.Utc;` notes the zone but displaying this to other counties at their own zone is not being possible with this. How to display time according to the clients time zone?

Comment: dupe? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/274826/how-to-get-client-date-and-time-in-asp-net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ASP.NET code works on server, so of cause it shows SERVER time.

If you need to get client time, it is the client how shound send this information to you.. at least the TimeZone where the client is located.

One of the suggested ways is to have hidden field on a form that would contain client time:

```
//html

<input type="hidden" id="clienttime"/>

//js

$(function () {

  $("#clienttime").val(new Date().toUTCString());

});
```

As soon as form submitted on server, you will get client time;

Answer (score 0):

Get the client's time using javascript?

I assume you are developing a web application. You could put in a custom block of javascript to do that using C#.

Just a headstart for you.

Comment: okay but what's in case if the client system displaying wrong time?

Comment: that could be rather comment, not answer;

Answer (score 0):

You need to ask the user for their own time zone, then use this information to convert the server's time to that zone.
See [TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.converttimefromutc.aspx).