# How to get the date time of client PC in asp.net C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get client date and time in ASP.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274826/how-to-get-client-date-and-time-in-asp-net)

I have a ASP.NET web application. My hosting server is in USA. Database is present there. 
Anyone can browse the site. Now I want to get the date time of client PC. I will store it in DB and will show it in browser. 
I have a label. I will show it in that label
I have searched it in Google. But did not found proper code.
Please give me the C# code.
[I am using asp.net, C#]
Thanks in advance
Rashed

Comment: dplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/274826/how-to-get-client-date-and-time-in-asp-net

Comment: not gonna happen in C#.. Gotta use client side code. Javascript ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

modified code from [This link:](http://forums.asp.net/p/1247758/2303034.aspx)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getDateTime()
{
    var localTime = new Date();
    var year= localTime.getYear();
    var month= localTime.getMonth() +1;
    var date = localTime.getDate();
    var hours = localTime .getHours();
    var minutes = localTime .getMinutes();
    var seconds = localTime .getSeconds();    
    //at this point you can do with your results whatever you please
}
</script>
```

At this point i would concatenate all of the fields together and put them in an asp:HiddenField control so they can be read on the server. On the server, call Convert.ToDateTime() on the Text value of your HiddenField.