# Client TimeZoneInfo

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

In ASP .NET (MVC 4), the following doesn't render in the client's local time.

```
@DateTime.UtcNow.ToLocalTime()
```

I want it to render in the client's local time. I believe I can do this by setting the thread's TimeZoneInfo on BeginRequest.

Is this the right (or an appropriate) way of handling timezones? And if so, how can I get the client's TimeZoneInfo inside BeginRequest so I can set it appropriately?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DateTime.UtcNow.ToLocalTime()` will give you the server's time. The best way is to let the user decide on his timezone in his account settings on your site.

You can use some Javascript tricks to find his timezone. See this question: [How to get client date and time in ASP.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274826/how-to-get-client-date-and-time-in-asp-net)

Comment: Any generic way to get this in a BeginRequest handler and change the current TimeZoneInfo?

Comment: Well, according to that question I linked you need to write some Javascript that will send you the user's local time and do the math yourself. What I usually do is store the user's timezone on his Session, but then again, I store it in the database as well on his account settings. Another way to cheat would be to format your dates as "X minutes ago" instead of actual dates. This will work regardless of the user's local time.