# How do I Implement Globalization and Localization in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, localization, globalization

Suppose if someone opens my site from India it should show Indian time of if someone opens this site from US it should display their local time. 
How can i do it.
Plz help me out

Thanks in advance
cpVariyani

Answer (score 0):

Your question should provide more detail and describe what you have already tried.

The best/easiest way is javascript - good option that leads to what I might guess is a middle ground for you here: [How to get client date and time in ASP.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274826/how-to-get-client-date-and-time-in-asp-net)

If you don't want to use javascript you can try and determine it from the request headers, but this is less likely to consistently work. Found this in an answer that strangely also linked the first link above: http://weblogs.asp.net/mikebosch/archive/2007/11/15/getting-the-client-browsers-date-and-time-with-asp-net.aspx

Comment: Why not? What are you still trying to accomplish?